# What did Ubuntu 17.04 (Zesty Zapus) do to my ssh-agent?

Tags: ssh, 17.04, ssh-agent

I just upgraded my Ubuntu 16.10 install to Ubuntu 17.04 and have found that I no longer have a working ssh-agent:

```
$ ssh-add my_rsa_key
Error connecting to agent: No such file or directory
$
```

Upon minimal investigation, I see that `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is set to something that doesn't appear to make sense:

```
$ env | grep SSH
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/openssh_agent
SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER=openssh
$
```

I don't know what is responsible for `/run/user/1000/openssh_agent` but it's not working on my system:

```
$ ls /run/user/1000/openssh_agent
ls: cannot access '/run/user/1000/openssh_agent': No such file or directory
```

I had a working ssh-agent on Ubuntu 16.10 after I added `eval $(ssh-agent)` as a "startup application".  This is still present and there is an ssh-agent running but I don't appear to have the correct agent env vars set anymore.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://sampablokuper.github.io/update/2018/02/13/gnome-keyring-ssh-agent-workaround/) might help:

> 1. Ensure that a reasonably up-to-date version of the OpenSSH SSH Agent is    installed.
> 2. Add this to `~/.bashrc`:
>
>    ```
>    if ! pgrep -u "$USER" ssh-agent > /dev/null; then
>        ssh-agent > ~/.ssh-agent-thing
>    fi
>    eval "$(cat ~/.ssh-agent-thing)" >& /dev/null
>    ```
> 3. Using GNOME Tweak Tool, go to "Startup Applications" and remove "Passwords    and Keys".
> 4. Add this to `~/.pam_environment`:
>
>    ```
>    GSM_SKIP_SSH_AGENT_WORKAROUND DEFAULT=1
>    ```
> 5. Log out of the GNOME Desktop Environment (or, if needed, reboot).
>
> After performing this workaround, running `ssh-agent` or `ssh-add`
>   from GNOME Terminal should result in OpenSSH's SSH agent being
>   invoked.